# Web application to communicate over serial port

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with a hardware serial port from a web application. What is the easiest, most straightforward way to accomplish this given the following:

- I have access to all the machines that need this browser-serial port functionality (~20)
- They are all windows machines running chrome
- The data being sent over the serial port will be encrypted

The desired end effect would be the user goes to a web page, fills out some data and an ajax call is made. On success, the page sends the encrypted command data over the serial port to the hardware. 
I've searched SO for related questions but none of them offered a satisfactory solution. I don't want to write a windows application that communicates with the system through an api, as that seems too cumbersome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if it suits your needs you should try developing a Google Chrome App. They can run in thier own window independant of the browser and acccess ports and the files sytem. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb

Answer (score 0):

RXTX will not work for accessing client com port from web browser